# C - calculate all dates from Year X to Year Y

Tags: c, for-loop, printf

*Please IGNORE, incompetence as its best!*

Just messing with some basic file i/o really, in some nested for Loops but the output isn't quite what I want, though I can't seem to get it working.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
FILE *pFile;
pFile = fopen("dates.txt", "w");
int day, month, year;
for(day = 1; day <= 31; day++) {
 for(month = 1; month <= 12; month++) {
   for(year = 1900; year <= 2050; year++) {
 if(day < 10 && month < 10) {
   fprintf(pFile, "0%d/0%d/%d\n", day, month, year);
 }else {
   fprintf(pFile, "%d/%d/%d\n", day, month, year);
 }
   }
 }
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Any tips much appreciated! And as a heads up, this isn't an homework task, just some experimentation really.

Cheers.

Comment: Don't forget to free `pFile`.

Comment: Try `%02d` as a format spec, it'll save you that `if` in the middle.

Comment: @Adban: `free()`?  You probably have `fclose()` in mind.  Good point.

Comment: you will have too many days in FEB, APR, JUN, SEP, and NOV.  Better use a solution like Shiplu's below.

Comment: You say the output isn't quite what you want. What do you want? It's a bit hard to answer without this bit of information.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `mktime` to create a date. Then add 1 day to it and create the next date.
This way you can iterate.

Following code shows first 200 dates.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    struct tm *lt;

    int i=200;

//time_t t=0;  // first second on epoch
    time_t t=-2209010000; // first second on 1900 (works on GCC, dind't test MSVS compiler)

    while(i--){
        lt = localtime(&t);
        printf("YYYY:MM:DD = %04d:%02d:%02d\n", lt->tm_year+1900, lt->tm_mon+1,     lt->tm_mday);
        lt->tm_hour+=24; // adding 24 hours
        t = mktime(lt);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

By the way it **works** dates behind **[epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)**. At least on my `gcc version 4.4.3` in `x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Not working for dates (too far) before the epoch could be a problem, especially on a 32-bit system where the stretch backwards gets you back to about Friday 13th December 1901 (unlucky for some!).  Similarly working forwards; 32-bit systems run out of steam in January 2038 with the epoch of 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +00:00.  The required range (1900-2050) exceeds those limits.  On a 64-bit system, you might well be OK.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler See the update. It shows date from 1900. Is it due to 64 bit Linux? I am not sure. All my systems are 64 bit.

Comment: Yes - 64-bit systems like MacOS X work fine backwards towards (beyond?) 1 AD (CE), and forwards beyond 9999 AD (CE).  32-bit systems are limited to ±68 years (give or take a month or so) either side of the epoch.  And when I say '32-bit systems, I mean systems where `time_t` is a 32-bit signed type (which is/was the case with most 32-bit systems).

Answer (score 1):

You can actually have 4 combinations of day and month in which you may or may not prefix with 0, which you are trying to handle with single if else.

Case 1: Both day and month  <10, handled by first if.

Case 2: Day > 10 and Month < 10, un-handled

Case 3: Day < 10 and Month > 10, un-handled

Case 4: Both are > 10. Handled in else.

%02d is the option to handle all the cases.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the year loop before the month loop before the day loop (the reverse of the current order).

You are going to need to make the testing for maximum day of the month cleverer (you need to know the rules for leap years (noting that 1900 was not a leap year, pace MS Excel, and 2000 was).

You can use `%02d` or `%.2d` to print 2 digits for the month and day, so you only need a single `printf()` statement.